# Looping through all combinations of row products in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix called `Dataset` which contains high throughput data like below :

```
     V1 V2 V3
 A   2  3  3     
 B   4  2  7
 C   3  1  4
```

What I want to do is find all combinations of row products for this matrix in the form of a list, as shown below (I'll call it `Comb`):

```
      V1 V2 V3
A A   4  9  9
A B   8  6  21
A C   6  3  12
B B   16 4  49  
B C   12 2  28
C C   9  1  16
```

What I have so far is the following:

```
combs <- combn(seq_len(nrow(Dataset)), 2)
Comb <- Dataset[combs[1,], ] * Dataset[combs[2,], ]
rownames(Comb) <- apply(combn(rownames(Dataset), 2), 2, paste, collapse = " ")
```

Unfortunately, the main problem in using this script I don't get the products of rows that are multiplied by themselves. So using the above script, I would get the following matrix:

```
      V1 V2 V3
A B   8  6  21
A C   6  3  12
B C   12 2  28
```

So I was wondering if it would be possible to modify the code I have in such a way that it would multiply the values in the same row together? Or would there be another to do this that might be more efficient? When I tried the script on a high throughput dataset (which is fairly large), it seemed to take several seconds to output a list for a table with 1000 rows, so if anyone knows of a way to do this task that might be faster, I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minimal adaptation of your implementation.  We just add to your `combn` result the values you want, and then pretty much just use the same logic:

```
r.seq <- seq_len(nrow(Dataset))
combs <- matrix(c(combn(r.seq, 2), rep(r.seq, each=2)), nrow=2)  # notice how we add values here
Comb <- Dataset[combs[1,], ] * Dataset[combs[2,], ]
rownames(Comb) <- apply(matrix(rownames(Dataset)[c(combs)], nrow=2), 2, paste, collapse=" ")
```

Produces:

```
    V1 V2 V3
A B  8  6 21
A C  6  3 12
B C 12  2 28
A A  4  9  9
B B 16  4 49
C C  9  1 16
```

You can always sort by rowname too.  One advantage over expand grid is that this only calculates the combinations you want.

Comment: Thanks, I just have a quick question. How would you sort the outputted list by rowname? I want to make sure that it's always in the same order that I have in my output matrix (so A A, then A B, then A C, then B B, etc.) regardless of whether A comes before B alphabetically (since these are genes, it's probably not going to be in alphabetical order).

Comment: @NelLau, `Comb[order(rownames(Comb)), ]`

Comment: Is there a way to order the combinations such that I'll get all combinations of the first row in the same order as in the original matrix? So the first row of the output matrix would be the combination of row 1 and itself (from the original matrix), the second row would be the combination of row 1 and row 2, third row would be the combination of row 1 and row 3, etc. Because I think `Comb[order(rownames(Comb)), ]` seems to order everything alphabetically, but my initial matrix may not be in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

You may apply `expand.grid` on the sequence of rows ('d1'), subset the 'df1' rows using the columns of ('d1'), multiply.  Create an index ('indx') of row names with `outer` to remove the rows that are not needed.

```
d1 <- expand.grid(1:nrow(df1), 1:nrow(df1))
res <- df1[d1[,1],] * df1[d1[,2],]
indx <- outer(rownames(df1), rownames(df1), FUN=paste)
v1 <- indx[upper.tri(indx, diag=TRUE)]
res1 <- res[do.call(paste,expand.grid(rownames(df1), rownames(df1))) %in% v1,]
row.names(res1) <- v1
res1
#   V1 V2 V3 
#A A  4  9  9
#A B  8  6 21
#B B 16  4 49
#A C  6  3 12
#B C 12  2 28
#C C  9  1 16
```

Comment: Would this method work if I have only one data column in my matrix as well? So for the original matrix  I would only have a row names column and V1, for example. I seem to get an error indicating an incorrect number of dimensions when I run `res1 <- res[do.call(paste,expand.grid(rownames(df1), rownames(df1))) %in% v1,]`, saying that the number of dimensions is incorrect when there's only one column with numerical values in it (or it might just be a mistake on my part, but I'm not sure).

Comment: I assumed that `df1` is a data.frame.  So, `df1 <- data.frame(df1)`  For a single column, you have to add `drop=FALSE` to avoid converting to vecftor.  i..e `res <- df1[d1[,1],,drop=FALSE] * df1[d1[,2],,drop=FALSE]` and `res1 <- res[do.call(paste,expand.grid(rownames(df1), rownames(df1))) %in% v1,, drop=FALSE]`.  But, I think BrodieG's solution is better and I would expect it to be more efficient